# Moderncv add a third column for skills

Tags: templates, moderncv

I currently use the moderncv template* and  would like to add a third column at the left (skills column) in order to make a shorter CV and to valorise the skills.

[image: Heberger image]

Something more like that:

[image: Heberger image]

Could you help me please ?

Comment: This is possible by *completely* redefining all that `moderncv` does. If you want to have that layout, it would be better to start from scratch instead of using hammers and screwdrivers to amend a ready made thing to your needs.

Comment: Keyword: Twenty seconds resume cv

Comment: Thank you. I know the 20 sec cv and love it but my friends in human ressources  told me that it wasn't an apealing one because of there is tons  of this one on work market...:(